# ElasticSearch - query_shard_exception | No mapping found for [timestamp] in order to sort on-Works through kibana dev tools but 400 error through API

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Facing a weird issue in querying Elastic search where the query is giving correct response when run through Kibana dev tools but hitting through Rest API is giving 400 error of No mapping found. Below are the details.
Query through Kibana dev tool :

GET diagnostics/_search?pretty=true&q=OTA4MjYxODM3NQ&size=6&sort=timestamp:desc

Getting response on the above query :

```
    {
      "took": 0,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 22,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
          {
    .......
    }
    ]
    }
```

But when I am hitting the same through Rest API below is the scenario :
API - http://IP:9200/diagnostics/_search?pretty=true&q=OTA4MjYxODM3NQ&size=6&sort=timestamp:desc

Response :

```
    {
        "error": {
            "root_cause": [
                {
                    "type": "query_shard_exception",
                    "reason": "No mapping found for [timestamp] in order to sort on",
                    "index_uuid": "JYOLtQ_URBGKnhxUWzD3dA",
                    "index": "diagnostics"
                }
            ],
            "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
            "reason": "all shards failed",
            "phase": "query",
            "grouped": true,
            "failed_shards": [
                {
                    "shard": 0,
                    "index": "diagnostics",
                    "node": "kisW84q1SbKEz7KQiOtY7Q",
                    "reason": {
                        "type": "query_shard_exception",
                        "reason": "No mapping found for [timestamp] in order to sort on",
                        "index_uuid": "JYOLtQ_URBGKnhxUWzD3dA",
                        "index": "diagnostics"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "status": 400
    }
```

Please help me as I find this very strange as through code when I am calling API, it is failing and I am stuck to understand the root cause of this.

GET diagnostics details

```
http://IP(A):9200/diagnostics
{
    "diagnostics": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {},
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1613465495276",
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "number_of_replicas": "0",
                "uuid": "JYOLtQ_URBGKnhxUWzD3dA",
                "version": {
                    "created": "5050199"
                },
                "provided_name": "diagnostics"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Through Kibana dev tools running on IP(A):5601-

```
GET diagnostics
{
  "diagnostics": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "results": {
        "properties": {
details are present here....
}
"number_of_shards": "5",
        "provided_name": "diagnostics",
        "creation_date": "1545374854111",
        "number_of_replicas": "0",
        "uuid": "CB7Vci8MTNiW2F85_S4z4Q",
        "version": {
          "created": "5050199"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you get when running `GET diagnostics`? Also, are you sure you're hitting the same endpoint?

Comment: @Val, when running GET diagnostics in Kibana, I get a list of parameters of the JSON and through API call /diagnostics  gives 200 ok with details like {
    "diagnostics": {"aliases": {},"mappings": {},
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                ....,
                "provided_name": "diagnostics"
            }
        }
    }
}  Yes I am hitting the same endpoint. In kibana through dev tools  the port is of kibana ie 5601 and while API call it is 9200 of ES

Comment: Your `diagnostics` mappings is really empty??

Comment: @Val, through kibana dev tools, mappings are not empty but empty through API calls. Even now i observed that the creation data & uuid are different in both case. I am pointing to the same IP in both cases only port is diff so I wonder this difference should not come.  Edited the question with those additional details

Comment: In your kibana.yml file, what is the value of the `elasticsearch.hosts` setting? Is it the same endpoint as `IP(A)` above?

Comment: @Val, You got the catch !!! Both are different IPs. The ES used to run on sam IP but recently it was moved to another set up by the DevOps guy which I was unaware of. Thank you for the troubleshooting. My system is up & working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certain that your Kibana is pointing to another running instance of Elasticsearch.

Make sure that the IP in the kibana.yml file under the setting `elasticsearch.hosts` is the same as `IP(A)`.